# Fill DetailsView.DataSource with anonymous type

Tags: c#, asp.net, anonymous-types

I have an `asp:DetailsView` with several columns, e.g. Foo, Bar.

I want to fill it with an anonymous type, i.e.:

```
gridView.DataSource = new { Foo = 1, Bar = "2" };
gridVeew.DataBind();
```

But getting next error:

> Data source is an invalid type.  It
>   must be either an IListSource,
>   IEnumerable, or IDataSource.

How can I do what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DataSource property expects a collection. The value you are assigning is not a collection.

You will have to create a collection and put the anonymous typed instance into that collection. The following should probably work (though I've not tested it with DataSource):

```
gridView.DataSource = new[] {new {Foo = 1, Bar = "2"}};
```

Comment: Very strange. I tried it myself, but got the same error. And after that decided to ask help here. So I had to rebuild project or something like that.. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, annoying when that happens! Anyway, glad to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
var list = from item in myList 
        select new { Foo = item.Foo, Bar = item.Bar.ToString() };
gridView.DataSource = list;
gridView.DataBind();
```

Which assumes you have a myList of `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 0):

You should have a collection containing your anonymous type.
Look at this example I found in [this blog](http://kirillosenkov.blogspot.com/2008/01/how-to-create-generic-list-of-anonymous.html)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var Customer = new { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
    var customerList = MakeList(Customer);

    customerList.Add(new { FirstName = "Bill", LastName = "Smith" });
    //then you can bind this collection
    gridView.DataSource = customerList;
    gridVeew.DataBind();
}

public static List<T> MakeList<T>(T itemOftype)
{
    List<T> newList = new List<T>();
    return newList;
}
```

Comment: The generic method trick is nice. But in this case unnecessary since the DataSource doesn't require a strongly typed collection.

Comment: Right Peter. Your answer is incredibly simple and clever